# Issue with transforming from frames to divs

Tags: html, transform, transformation, frames

I want to rebuild my quite old frames build website (http://fleets.alltrams.com/) to a website build with divs. The usage of frames is not recommended anymore and it is a great plus to have a different url for each page (city in the list).

I know how to build a div website but there is one thing of the frames system I don't know how to get in the div system. When scrolling to a city in the menu on the left and clicking it, the page will load in the right frame, but the scrolled position in the menu will stay so as the name of the city will stay selected. I like this cause you can still see what you have clicked and its easy to click nearby cities. I don't know how to make this working in divs, cause there the full page will renew so the menu will be shown from top again.

I hope above is clear enough to understand my issue. My technical English and jargon is not that good haha.

Looking forward to your help!

Comment: If you don't want page to reload use Ajax

Comment: Its not about reloading. Its just that a new page will be loaded so the menu will be "renewed". This should not happen or the renewed menu should auto jump to the previous scrolled position.

Comment: If you listen to my advice you'll learn something new and will realize you can just update single divs on click and get something close to now. Anyway good luck with your work!